# Turning range of indices to 0 for every case in r

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing, mapply

I am trying to set a range of indices (5 to a variable index) to 0 in a huge dataframe for every case:

What I have come up with:

```
mapply(function(x,y,z) df[x, y:z] = 0, seq_len(nrow(df)), 5, df$index)
```

So for example, for the first case, if the index is 10, then df[1,5:10] should be turned into 0s.

Comment: In your previous example, you specifically asked for an `ifelse` solution

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
mapply(function(x,y,z)  numeric(length(df[x, y:z])), 
       seq_len(nrow(df)), 5, df$index)
```